# Using List Option, Within single ID image using as Slider

Tags: flutter

```
class QuotationResources {
 
  final String price,vehicleShowcase,vehicleShowcaseLeft,vehicleShowcaseRight,vehicleShowcaseRear; 
 QuotationResources({
    this.vehicleNumber,
    this.vehicleShowcase,
    this.vehicleShowcaseLeft,
    this.vehicleShowcaseRight,
    this.vehicleShowcaseRear,
    this.price,
  });
}
 
List<QuotationResources> quotationResources = [
  QuotationResources(
    id: 1,
    vehicleShowcase: "assets/images/truck_1.jpeg",
    vehicleShowcaseLeft: "assets/images/truck_2.jpg",
    vehicleShowcaseRight: "assets/images/truck_3.jpg",
    vehicleShowcaseRear: "assets/images/truck_4.jpeg" ),
];
```

Basically I just want to slider, How to use id=1 images as sliders (like vehicleShowcase,
vehicleShowcaseLeft, vehicleShowcaseRight, vehicleShowcaseRear), below image I need to add in the this format

image: AssetImage(quotationResources.vehicleShowcase),

Comment: Please add some screenshot as your requirement, It is not that clear by just looking at the codes and text.

Comment: Updated code hope it can be understand